# Odata query filtering first element of a list

Tags: odata

I have an OData query working fine, returning me something like:

```
    [
        {
            "Id": "ABC",
            "Related": {
                "Id": "123"
            },
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "DEF",
            "Related": {
                "Id": "123"
            },
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Id": "3"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to filter on the first children of every object.
I have no problem filtering on the value or Related (1-1 relation), but I cannot find a way to filter on the first children (0-N relation).

To filter on the 1-1 entity, I do the filter with **Related/Id eq '123'**, but I could not find a syntax similar to **Children[0]/Id eq '1'**.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share an example URL and tag this question with the OData protocol version. There is support for this in OData v4 but it is different to the previous versions

Answer (score 1):

In OData v4, you would use `$top` inside the `$expand` option:

```
/odata/resources?$expand=Related,Children($top=1)
```

However you should always specify the sort order when you are limiting the results with $top, this example uses Id descending for no other reason than so you can see the syntax

```
/odata/resources?$expand=Related,Children($top=1;$orderby=Id desc)
```

You could also use $filter to get a specific record by id in the child,

If you had used a filter on the outer node, based on the existence of the child node, then you would also need to apply the same (or similar) filter expression to the expansion node if you didn't want to see the other children:

```
/odata/resources?$filter=Children/any(x:x/Id eq 4)&$expand=Related,Children($filter=Id eq 4)
```